# PHP background loading data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a small PHP based application, based on CodeIgniter framework, using also jquery.

I have a bunch of data, what I wan to show to the users, however it takes 5-10 seconds to load.

I would like to be this page responsive, and load the data in chunks in the background.
So for example: load the first 200 items, and then load the rest in the background, and update the gui.

What should be the simple/best solution for that?

The technologies are available: AJAX, php (with codeigniter framework), jquery.

Thanks the answers in advance!

Comment: You can use datatable if the data is in tabular format or lazy loading as well

Comment: show data in grib? if yes, what do you use ?

Comment: Can you use pagination? break it up so only 20 or 100 items show per page? Then load those specific records based on the page.

Answer (score 0):

After years of using datatbles for such cases, I would recommend to read the following: [Datatables AJAX Deferred Loading](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html)

There are of course other solutions, but I find datatables the easiest one for this case. Few lines of code, many working hours saved.